A topology different from discrete and anti-discrete, in which every open set is closed, and every closed set is open.
To give an example of a topology on a set of four points, different from discrete and anti-discrete, in which every open set is closed, and every closed set is open.I have 0 ideas at all, I thought that just the same, that only a discrete topology has such characteristics for sets.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". So, share some minimal thoughts. Like noticing that your 'and every closed set is open' is redundant. Or looking at the same question on a set of 3 points.

$$\mathcal{T} = \{\varnothing, \{a, b\}, \{c, d\}, \{a, b, c, d\}\}$$

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
